# Google Apps Script: How to get this code run after UI is closed?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

This may seem a very newbie question, but I'm stuck with it. I've got this code to show a check list in a UI and insert the paragraphs of one or more documents into another target document:

```
 var fact_list = [ ["Kennedy Inauguration", "politics", "tZwnNdFNkNklYc3pVUzZINUV4eUtWVWFSVEf"], ["Pericles’ Funeral Oration", "politics", "sdgrewaNkNklYc3pVUzZINUV4eUtW345ufaZ"], ["The Pleasure of Books", "culture", "1234rFszdgrfYc3pVUzZINUV4eU43usacd"], ["I Am The First Accused (Nelson Mandela)", "law", "34rsgadOsidjSZIswjadi95uydnfklsdks"] ];
    function showList() {
        var mydoc = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
        var app = UiApp.createApplication();
        var panel = app.createVerticalPanel().setId('panel');
        // Store the number of items in the array (fact_list)
        panel.add(app.createHidden('checkbox_total', fact_list.length));
        // add 1 checkbox + 1 hidden field per item 
        for(var i = 0; i < fact_list.length; i++){
          var checkbox = app.createCheckBox().setName('checkbox_isChecked_'+i).setText(fact_list[i][0]);
          var hidden = app.createHidden('checkbox_value_'+i, fact_list[i]);
          panel.add(checkbox).add(hidden);
        }
        var handler = app.createServerHandler('submit').addCallbackElement(panel);
        panel.add(app.createButton('Submit', handler));
        app.add(panel);
        mydoc.show(app);
    }

    function submit(e){
      var numberOfItems = e.parameter.checkbox_total;
      var itemsSelected = [];
      // for each item, if it is checked / selected, add it to itemsSelected
      for(var i = 0; i < numberOfItems; i++){
        if(e.parameter['checkbox_isChecked_'+i] == 'true'){
          itemsSelected.push(e.parameter['checkbox_value_'+i]);
        }
      }
      var app = UiApp.getActiveApplication();
      ScriptProperties.setProperties({'theses': itemsSelected}, true);
      app.close();
      return app;
    }


    function importTheses(targetDocId, thesesId, thesesType) { // adapted from Serge insas
      var targetDoc = DocumentApp.openById(targetDocId);
      var targetDocParagraphs = targetDoc.getParagraphs();
      var targetDocElements = targetDocParagraphs.getNumChildren();

      var thesesDoc = DocumentApp.openById(thesesId);
      var thesesParagraphs = thesesDoc.getParagraphs();
      var thesesElements = thesesDoc.getNumChildren();

      var eltargetDoc=[];
      var elTheses=[];

      for( var j = 0; j < targetDocElements; ++j ) {
           var targetDocElement = targetDoc.getChild(j);
    //      Logger.log(j + " : " + type);// to see targetDoc's content
            eltargetDoc[j]=targetDocElement.getText();
           if(el[j]== thesesType){
               for( var k = 0; k < thesesParagraphs-1; ++k ) {
                   var thesesElement = thesesDoc.getChild(k);
                   elTheses[k] = thesesDoc.getText();
                   targetDoc.insertParagraph(j, elTheses[k]);
             }
          }
       }
    }
```

But when I call these functions inside my main function, I got a red message (in my language): `service not available: Docs` and, after the UI from `showList()` is closed, nothing more happens with my code (but I wanted the main functions continues to run). I call these functions this way:

```
  if (theses == 1){
    showList();
    var thesesArrays = ScriptProperties.getProperty('theses');
    for (var i = 0; i < thesesArrays.lenght(); i++){
      var thesesId = ScriptProperties.getProperty('theses')[i][2];
      var thesesType = ScriptProperties.getProperty('theses')[i][1];
      importTheses(target, thesesId, thesesType);
    }
  }      
  showURL(docName, link); //  Shows document name and link in UI
```

So, how can I fix that? How can I get the code run until the line `showURL(docName, link);`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
showList();
```

This function creates only Ui.

You are setting the script properties only in the Server Handler which executes on the click of submit button. Since then:

```
    ScriptProperties.getProperty('theses');
```

will hold nothing. So you need to call these lines:

```
var thesesArrays = ScriptProperties.getProperty('theses');
for (var i = 0; i < thesesArrays.lenght(); i++){
  var thesesId = ScriptProperties.getProperty('theses')[i][2];
  var thesesType = ScriptProperties.getProperty('theses')[i][1];
  importTheses(target, thesesId, thesesType);
}
```

Inside server handler or put them inside a method and call the method from the server Handler.

Comment: Hi, @Bharathi, thanks for your answer. I tried the suggestion. Now I got running the last code line `showURL(docName, link);`. But when the `showList()` function starts running, it opens and close the UI in a fraction of second, without wating for the handler function `submit(e)`. Any idea of what is hapenning?

Comment: Hi, @Bharathi, the lines after the `showList()` calling aren't being executed. I'll start other question.

Comment: I am not getting your question. Can you be more clear.